# What's the SQL function for timestamp manipulation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and the time functions are different than mySQL so I'm having a terrible time finding a good site reference with USEFUL timestamp queries.

I'm not able to locate the correct way of doing this query in SQL:

```
Id          Timestamp
-----------------------------------
1145744 2012-10-10 18:15:11.500
1145743 2012-10-10 18:15:11.313
1145742 2012-10-10 18:15:11.313
1145741 2012-10-10 18:15:11.253
1145740 2012-10-10 18:15:11.190
1145739 2012-10-10 18:15:11.190
1145738 2012-10-10 18:15:11.127
1145737 2012-10-10 18:15:11.067
1145736 2012-10-10 18:15:11.063
1145735 2012-10-10 18:15:10.940
1145734 2012-10-10 18:15:10.817


SELECT * from table WHERE Timestamp ... RANGE
```

I need the range of 2 timestamps so I can select rows by the following parameters:

1. second range
2. minute range
3. hour range
4. day range
5. week range
6. month range
7. year range

Is there one function to put in 2 timestamps and get the range?  or is this a mix of functions I need?

Any good site references would be greatly appriceated. MSDN site isn't helping me isolate the proper way of doing this. I've been searching for about an hour trying to get the last day from 1:30PM to 1:30PM today.

Comment: A range is a range. If you give it `@d1, @d2`, it will find anything between `@d1, @d2`. Can you explain a bit more about "hour range" for instance?

Comment: THanks, yes, I need to calculate all the ids between the hours of 10-11, or 1-5 etc.  I'm not to familiar with variables.  Is this how I would write that query?  SELECT Timestamp = @d1,* FROM table WHERE RANGE(@d1,NEWDATE('dd',@d1,-1));

Comment: `I need to calculate all the ids between the hours of 10-11, or 1-5` An hour in a single day, or 10-11 across many days?

Comment: Sorry, yes an hour in a single day, and also something like 1:30pm yesterday - 3am today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <code>DATEPART</code> to get:

`second,
    minute,
    hour,
    day,
    week,
    month,
    year`

[Reference for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28loband%29.aspx).

Use the `where` condition to get the desired range.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the function I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time figuring out what you really want.  Here are some examples based on your comments so far:

**10-11, or 1-5**

```
SELECT * from table WHERE Timestamp >= '20121011 10:00'
                      and Timestamp <  '20121011 11:00'
SELECT * from table WHERE Timestamp >= '20121011 01:00'
                      and Timestamp <  '20121011 05:00'
```

Or if you need "today" to automatically change, then

```
SELECT * from table WHERE Timestamp >= DateAdd(Hour,10,CAST(GetDate() as Date))
                      and Timestamp <  DateAdd(Hour,11,CAST(GetDate() as Date))
```

**1:30pm yesterday - 3am today**

```
SELECT * from table WHERE Timestamp >= '20121010 13:30'
                      and Timestamp <  '20121011 03:00'
```

**yes an hour in a single day**
Now, if you were to use DATEPART to solve this, let's say for 10-11

```
SELECT * from table WHERE DATEPART(hour,Timestamp) = 10
```

That would run across days and would not be [SARGABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), i.e. it cannot be searched on an index which is really not what you want.

---

Where do these come in?

- second range
- minute range
- hour range
- day range
- week range
- month range
- year range

Comment: I was trying to look for the proper way to select for example rows 2012-10-10 18:15:11.253 through rows 2012-10-10 18:15:11.313

Comment: How does DATEPART help with that?

Comment: I was able to get it to work with datepart.   DECLARE currentopen datetime = convert(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) + ' 06:30:00');  DECLARE currentclose datetime = convert(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) + ' 13:15:00'); SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >= currentopen AND timestamp <= currentclose;  This is done for yesterday, tomorrow and current. When the time goes after 1:30pm, the query changes.  Is there a better way?